# How to use Datapower URL for MobileFirst 8.0 applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, ibm-datapower

Couple of questions -

1. How can we configure DataPower url for individual application on MFP 8 server? In MFP 6.3 I have used conextroot to separate the applications, here in MFP8 I am not sure where and what is the contextroot of application.
2. I have created different LDAP groups for every application on MFP8 server. Where can I set/configure these groups as in server.xml, there is no settings for individual application.
3. Where can I find the settings for each application on server like server.xml in server folder.

I have downloaded the DataPowerCordova sample code. I set the DP URL as below -

https://:443/DataPowerCordova/* pointing to 
http://mymfpserver:9080/DataPowerCordova

but getting the error "Service not available. Try again later."

Please help on this

Thanks
Lalit

Comment: Have you reviewed the blog entry that discusses this exact topic, at https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/datapower-integration/ ?

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it. But it is not mentioned that what should be the end point for the datapower. they mentioned that use full URL to your MobileFirst server context (http(s)://hostname:port/ProjectName).
What will be the ProjectName? is it same as application name which displays in mfp console?

Comment: That will be the runtime you have configured

Comment: the default runtime is mfp. I need to map different Datapower URL for each application. So what will the end point of an application in MFP server?